# Anyone know how to encrypt something into XOR with a key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to use vanilla JavaScript to encrypt a string with a key in XOR. Anyone know how?

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. show what you've done so far.

Comment: What format do you want to have output in?

Comment: In a string, like it gets encrypted in XOR with a key then it gives me the output. Also, this is not a homework assignment and I dont have anything yet really since im not good with encryptions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't described your question with detail, I'd make some assumptions along the way.

Let's say you want to encrypt `"password"` with  <strike>key `"secret"`. for convenience, we lengthen the key to the length of the word we want to encrypt.  in this case, `"password"` is 8 chars long, so `"secret"` will be `"secretse"`.</strike>  key = `"secretse"` (be aware that secret should be as long as (or longer than) the word itself)

```
const word = "password"

const key = "secretse"

const encrypted = word.split('').map((character, index) =>
 String.fromCharCode(word.charCodeAt(index) ^ key.charCodeAt(index))).join()
```

We use `^` operator to XOR numbers in JS.

Comment: "*for convenience, we lengthen the key to the length of the word we want to encrypt.*" - you should mention that this convenience destroys any security of the cypher.

Comment: @Bergi You're right! Thanks! will edit my answer.